# How to change username/password for CmEnvironment in Topology manager

Tags: web8.5, topology-manager

We are using SDL Web8.5 we have changed MTSUser password on CMS Machine. How can we change password of CmEnvironment in Topology manager.

Answer (score 7):

To run the following PowerShell command to Update an existing Content Manager Environment in the Topology Manager:

**Syntax**

```
  Set-TtmCmEnvironment -Id <String> [-WebsiteRootUrl <String>] [-CoreServiceRootUrl &lt;String&gt;] [-AuthenticationType <Nullable`1[AuthenticationType]>] [-ExtensionProperties <Hashtable>] [-TtmServiceUrl <String>] [<CommonParameters>]

  Set-TtmCmEnvironment [-Data] <CmEnvironmentData> [-TtmServiceUrl <String>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

**Example:**

```
Set-TtmCmEnvironment -Id TridionCM_localhost -AuthenticationType Windows -UserName "domain\MTSUser" -Password "xxxxx" -WebsiteRootUrl http://localhost/
```

**Description**
    The Set-TtmCmEnvironment cmdlet updates an existing CM Environment in the Topology Manager.
    Only properties specified by the user will be updated.
    If an item with specified Id does not exist, an exception will be thrown.
    The command will fail if Topology Manager cannot connect to specified Content Manager Environment with given Credentials.

Answer (score 4):

***Left here for further info*** - but this answer would be for **updating the database connection string** for the Topology Manager, **not** the specific CMEnvironment user password as required

*The paths below assume default install paths - update as per your environment*

Take a backup of the TM web.config file in  "C:\Program Files (x86)\SDL Web\TopologyManager\web"

Execute the cmd: 
`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -pdf "database" "C:\Program Files (x86)\SDL Web\TopologyManager\web"`

You will now see the database node is unencrypted

e.g. `<database server="[[database-server]]" name="Tridion_Topology" username="TTMDBUser" password="[[TTMDBUser-Password]]" authenticationMethod="Normal" />`

Update the details until your heart is content.

Execute the cmd: 
`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -pef "database" "C:\Program Files (x86)\SDL Web\TopologyManager\web"`

-- Done --

Comment: This is the procedure you can use if you want to change the database settings for Topology Manager (same trick can be used for Content Manager). However, it doesn’t seem to be an Answer to the Question to me?

Comment: Hi Rick, Id' rushed the answer assuming that the requirement *was* to change the database password - of course, re-reading _"we have changed MTSUser password on CMS Machine."_ I can see the setting of the CMEnviornment through Powershell would make more sense :)

Comment: This helped resetting the password for Topology Manager. -Thanks